# How to drop a pin from variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

I want to drop a pin using data that is saved on to JavaScript Variables, x and y. How can I do that? Below is the code to drop a pin and get coordinates, is there a way I can change it so that I drop the pin using data that is saved on variables?

```js
<script>
      require([
        "esri/widgets/Sketch",
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/views/MapView"
      ], function(Sketch, Map, GraphicsLayer, MapView) {
        const layer = new GraphicsLayer();

        const map = new Map({
          basemap: "streets",
          layers: [layer]
        });

        const view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          zoom: 5,
          center: [90, 45]
        });
  
  var symbol = {
                    type: "simple-marker",  // autocasts as new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
                    style: "circle",
                    color: "blue",
                    size: "8px",  // pixels
                    outline: {  // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
                    color: [ 255, 255, 0 ],
                    width: 1  // points
                    }
                };

        const sketch = new Sketch({
          layer: layer,
          view: view,
    symbol: symbol,
          availableCreateTools: ["point"]
        });

        view.ui.add(sketch, "top-right");
        
        sketch.on('create', function (evt) {
        if (view.zoom >= 11) {
   // check if the create event's state has changed to complete indicating
            // the graphic create operation is completed.
          let gra = evt.graphic.clone();
          evt.graphic.layer.removeAll();
          gra.symbol.color = "blue";
          layer.add(gra);
          console.log("X = ", gra.geometry.x);
          console.log("Y = ", gra.geometry.y);
        } else {
          alert("please zoom in");
          evt.graphic.layer.remove(evt.graphic);
        }
      });
      });
    </script>
```

Please assist.

Comment: I don't now if I understand you correctly, you want to remove a graphic from the graphic layer? .. can you give an example about of the data that is saved in variables", what do you mean with that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, you want to add a point to the map using an X and Y value.

There's a tutorial for that - https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/display-point-line-and-polygon-graphics/

Simplifying that tutorial/sample to show just how to create a graphic based on a point (with X and y) and a symbol - https://codepen.io/bsvensson/pen/GRJeMeR

```
  // Create a point
  var point = {
    type: "point",
    longitude: -118.80657,
    latitude: 34.00059
  };
  var simpleMarkerSymbol = {
    type: "simple-marker",
    color: [226, 119, 40], // orange
    size: 30,
    style: "triangle", // default is a circle
    outline: {
      color: [255, 255, 255], // white
      width: 2
    }
  };
  var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
    geometry: point,
    symbol: simpleMarkerSymbol
  });
  graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);
```

Comment: Thanks Bjorn Svensson, let me try this.

Comment: Hi Bjorne Svensson, I tested the code you recommended it works 100%. But now I wanted to modify my code so that it is aligned to this code, when I run it it does not display the map, can you please advise on what am I doing wrong.  I have added my latest code to the original post.